# PowerBI - unpivot selected values from column

Tags: powerbi, pivot, transformation

I have a table which has a list of Id's and categories. See below:

| id | Category | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Pref 1 Region | MTO |
| 1 | Pref 1 Area | MT99 |
| 1 | Pref 1 Station | ST124 |
| 1 | Pref 2 Region | MTO |
| 1 | Pref 2 Area | MT85 |
| 1 | Pref 2 Station | ST420 |
| 1 | Pref 3 Region | BSW |
| 1 | Pref 3 Area | BS88 |
| 1 | Pref 3 Station | ST876 |
| 2 | Pref 1 Region | GRT |
| 2 | Pref 1 Area | GT34 |
| 2 | Pref 1 Station | STT555 |
| 2 | Pref 2 Region | MTO |
| 2 | Pref 2 Area | MT99 |
| 2 | Pref 2 Station | ST124 |
| 2 | Pref 3 Region | BSW |
| 2 | Pref 3 Area | BS88 |
| 2 | Pref 3 Station | ST876 |

I want to keep the Pref # Station and 'unpivot' the other categories Area and Region to separate columns, like below:

| id | Category | Value | Region | Area |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Pref 1 Station | ST124 | MTO | MT99 |
| 1 | Pref 2 Station | ST420 | MTO | MT85 |
| 1 | Pref 3 Station | ST876 | BSW | BS88 |
| 2 | Pref 1 Station | STT555 | GRT | GT34 |
| 2 | Pref 2 Station | ST124 | MTO | MT99 |
| 2 | Pref 3 Station | ST876 | BSW | BS88 |

I've tried unpivoting columns in PowerQuery but the order isn't kept. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Which order you are referring to? And what is your code so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will produce the 2nd table:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"id", Int64.Type}, {"Category", type text}, {"Value", type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type", "Category", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({" "}, QuoteStyle.Csv, true), {"Category.1", "Category.2"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Split Column by Delimiter", List.Distinct(#"Split Column by Delimiter"[Category.2]), "Category.2", "Value"),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Pivoted Column", {"id", "Category.1", "Region", "Area"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Unpivoted Columns",{"Category.1", "Attribute"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.None),"Category"),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Merged Columns",{"id", "Category", "Value", "Region", "Area"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```